# Displaying infinite scrolling lists

Tags: android, layout, widget

When setting an alarm in the android clock app there are two lists one for the hour and one for the minute.  Each list can "spin"  forward or backwards and goes from 0 to 23 (or 23 to 0 if spinning backwards).  Are these actually lists?  I want to replicate similar functionality in order to set 4 values each one being a hex digit.

Are these spinners actually lists?  Or is there some bespoke widget that will behave this way?